# Писать здесь НЕ слитно или раздельно: "не_проведение указанных мероприятий"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, частица-не

"Не проведение указанных мероприятий..." или "Непроведение указанных мероприятий..."?

Comment: Фразу целиком пишите.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **Непроведение** (= отсутствие) указанных мероприятий.

Здесь нет отрицания, это утвердительная конструкция.

**Из словаря:**

НЕПРОВЕДЕНИЕ,  ср. Офиц. Отказ от проведения чего-л. Н. ядерных испытаний. Контроль за непроведением подземных взрывов.

**Пример**

**Непроведение** последовательных и сжатых во времени стабилизационных мероприятий привело к гораздо худшим социальным результатам (В. Мау, 2001).

Comment: Не проведение указанных мероприятий, а подготовка к ним.

Comment: В принципе противопоставление возможно, то есть надо анализировать  полное предложение.  В то же время отрицательная конструкция  вряд ли будет находиться в начале предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Пишется слитно, так как это существительное и можно заменить синонимом без "не", например, пропуск или отсутствие.